# How can I dynamically alter the files in the /Content directory in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, actionresult

When I serve a javascript file to a user from the /Content Directory I want to replace a `string` token in that file with a value, so that when the user requests a given file, it has all the customizations they expect.

I think that means I need to somehow proxy requests to the /Content directory, perform the dynamic insertion, and give the file to the user.

- I'm interested in performing this insertion as a `stream` or as a in -memory file.  I'd prefer to use a stream just because it's probably more efficient memory wise.

How do I get ASP.NET to proxy this directory?

I've attempted

1. Using routes to point to a controller
2. WCF to proxy a URL

But they all seem "ugly" to me and I'd like to make this insertion/replacement as transparent as possible int he project.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create an action on a controller.

```
public class JavascriptController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Load(string file)
    {
        var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Content/{0}", file)));

        //make replacements io content here

        return this.Content(content, "application/javascript");
    }
}
```

You can then access the javascript like this (assuming you have the default routing):

```
http://localhost:53287/Javascript/Load?file=file.js
```

where file.js is the name of the file you are requesting.

Don't worry about the url, you can customise this by creating another route if necessary

Comment: Thank you.  What if I also want to proxy requests to a vendors (Telerik) dynamic javascript files?  Doesn't that operate at a lower level?

Comment: You can change the line which reads all the text from a file to request the file contents over http.. that is quite a simple solution, but more overhead (each request, would actually be processed twice)

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative answer to the answer I posted above, taking into account your comment regarding dynamic javascript.

Firstly, I don't know of a way to do this specifically using either mvc or wcf.. the only way I know how to do this is with a lower-level HttpModule

Take a look at the following code:

```
public class JavascriptReplacementModule : IHttpModule
{
    public class ResponseFilter : MemoryStream
    {
        private Stream outputStream = null;

        public ResponseFilter(Stream output)
        {
            outputStream = output;
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            base.Flush();
            this.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var sr = new StreamReader(this);

            string contentInBuffer = sr.ReadToEnd();

            //Do replacements here

            outputStream.Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentInBuffer), 0, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(contentInBuffer));

            outputStream.Flush();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            outputStream.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PostRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    void context_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var context = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/Content") && context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".js"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = new ResponseFilter(HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter);
        }
    }
}
```

And register the module like this (make sure you put the full type in the type attribute):

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="JavascriptReplacementModule" type="JavascriptReplacementModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This allows you to modify the output stream before it gets to the client

Comment: Thanks!  In case you're wondering I'm using this for a security solution relating to CORS and AJAX POSTs:  http://security.stackexchange.com/q/17036/396   I'd be curious to hear your thoughts about it if you had something come to mind :)